# The Javascript getElementsByClassName wont work

Tags: javascript

im trying to make a button that once click will make it so that the same javascript code would apply to the same class but it wont work

```js
function Destination() {
  hrs = Math.round(Math.random() * 12);
  mins = Math.round(Math.random() * 60);
  var hFormat = (hrs < 10 ? "0" : "");
  var mFormat = (mins < 10 ? "0" : "");
  var amPm = (hrs < 12 ? "AM" : "PM");
  return String(hFormat + hrs + ":" + mFormat + mins + " " + amPm);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('AirAsiaTable1').innerHTML =Destination(12,60)">
  <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: the return string where you wanted to show ?

Comment: You give two parameters in call to`destination` function, but the function doesn't use any of them.

Answer (score -1):

getElementsByClassName returns an array of elements (if there are any). You need to get the first one. Referenced by index 0.

Try This CodePen

```
function Destination() {
  hrs = Math.round(Math.random() * 12);
  mins = Math.round(Math.random() * 60);
  var hFormat = (hrs < 10 ? "0" : "");
  var mFormat = (mins < 10 ? "0" : "");
  var amPm = (hrs < 12 ? "AM" : "PM");
  return String(hFormat + hrs + ":" + mFormat + mins + " " + amPm);
}
function btnClick(){
  var p = document.getElementsByClassName('AirAsiaTable1')[0]
  console.log(p)
  p.innerHTML =Destination(12,60)
}
```

https://codepen.io/ianmiddelkamp/pen/MWYGWeK?editors=1111

Comment: thank you kind stranger the codes working normal now